# JQuery Masonry Fade-In Animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I would like to know if it is possible to rather have a **Masonry Fade-In animation, rather than the bricks flying in**. The flying bricks are quite graphically intensive on some computers and degrade user experience, such as on my MacBook Air using Google Chrome with CSS3 animations. I am using continuous scrolling and the scrolling is not smooth when the bricks fly into place.

I thought it might be better if the bricks fade in when they already are in their correct positions, without any movement.

PS: I could not find a solution anywhere and if I don't find a solution here, I will modify the Masonry code myself.

Comment: I wanted to see this built in too and was bummed to see nobody had an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution, but I didn't get it working:

http://life.innove.it/index.php/2011/08/jquery-masonry-with-fade-effect/

Comment: The second paragraph alone is a link-only answer (not welcome here - you should quote the relevents part here). The first paragraph doesn't add much and feels more like a question (and should be posted as such - while showing what you have tried - if you want an answer)